# Hide homepage when user is logged in

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, redirect

When the user is logged in and trying to access the homepage I need to redirect him to certain url. So basically when authorized user gets to www.example.com he's redirected to www.example.com/dashboard.

What's the way to do this?Joomla version is 3.3.6

Comment: Maybe consider rephrasing your question. Should homepage really be *hidden* from logged in user or you only want to send him to alternative landing page (keeping original home page still available)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've used [Nomad](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/system-nomad) in the past - instead of redirecting, it's a system plugin that actually *overrides* the default home page and replaces it with your choice of locations based on User Groups.

Comment: +1 for this. Was a bit skeptical when looking at the latest review for this, but definitely going to try this out myself

Comment: Just saw those for the newer Joomla...the sites we use it on haven't been upgraded yet due to a PHP version issue, but it's handy enough that I'd spend the time fixing it....a VERY nice to have.

Answer (score 4):

You can always use extension like this to redirect users on login:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/access-a-security/site-access/redirect-on-login

Comment: and what if they manually type in the URL?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to redirecting then when they **try** to access the homepage, you can also redirect them once they have logged in. To do this, open the Login module in the **Module Manager** and you will see an option on the left called **Login Redirection Page**.

For your main question though, this can't be achieved using htaccess, so instead you'll need to use PHP. At first I thought a menu item would do the trick but this will only work if they **click** on the menu item and not if they manually type in the URL.

So what I would do is, open you **index.php** for your template and add in the following:

```
$app  = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if( !$user->guest )
{
    if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) 
    {
        $app->redirect(JRoute::_(JUri::root().'/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Note: I quickly mocked this code up but haven't yet tested it, so let me know if it works or not.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks for your input. The script, unfortunately, did not work so I've decided to go with the Nomad extension

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a very simple way to do it in Joomla 3x.

1. Go to Users > Access Levels and click on the Guest access level. By default, under User Groups Having Viewing Access, only Guest is checked. Check the Public box as well and then click Save.
2. Go to your menu and click on the Home link to edit it. In the Access drop down on the right hand side, set it to Guest instead of Public and then click Save.

Voila! From now on your Home link will be hidden from users who are signed in.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did you edit my response?

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach, you can try a content restriction plugin like [OSD Content Restriction](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/access-a-security/site-access/osd-content-restriction). You won't have different homepages as you asked for, but you can show different content to guests and members in your articles (and Custom HTML modules) using the following tags:

```
{guest}
  This content is only visible to guest users, 
  and NOT visible to registered/logged in users.
{/guest}
{!guest}
  This content is NOT visible to guest users.
  Only logged-in users will be able to see it.
{/guest}
  Any content outside the tags will be visible to both guests and registered users.
```

What is shown or hidden can be determined by six different variables, namely the *user group*, the *user*, the *author group*, the *author*, if on the *homepage* or if an article is *featured*.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the quick and dirty method, ie a custom HTML that has registered for access and is visible only on the home page, then [redirect with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744751/how-do-i-redirect-with-javascript). It works well enough if the position is in the beginning of the page. I'd presume those plugins for adding custom javascript can do this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create two user groups "Guest" and "Register". Add home menu under "Guest group". Add other menus in "Register group". Add the user in "Register" group . So when a user logs in the guest menu is hidden. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently wanted to achieve exactly the same thing: provide different homepage for logged in users

The earlier plugin didn't get good reviews so I tried [Custom Member Homepage](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/custom-member-homepage) plugin. Works really well.